# SIGSEGV segmentation fault assembly

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I am getting a SIGSEGV, segmentation fault.

0x0000000000000400906 in findSum() at ast8procs.asm:250

The DDD is pointing to this line

mov r12, 0

;---

The whole function is

```
global  lstSum
lstSum:
push rsi
push r12
mov r12, 0
mov rbx, 0
findSum:
    add ebx, dword [rdi+r12*4]
    inc r12
    cmp r12, rsi
    jl findSum

    mov r12, qword [r9]
    mov dword [eax], ebx
sumExit:
    pop r12
    pop rsi


    ret
```

Comment: `mov dword [eax], ebx` looks suspicious to me. What's that supposed to do? Comment your code.

Comment: More importantly, where did you get a 76-bit CPU?

Comment: Could it be that the exception actually happened a bit earlier? Maybe the stack was misaligned?